# How do I publish copied nodes from Umbraco 7?

Tags: umbraco7

I copied a parent content node and all its set of content child nodes from an Umbraco 7 web app and I see them all in a gray status as they are not published and actually, they aren't (I see them all in a gray color). I have to manually edit each node and save to get them published. I tried to execute the option "Republish entire site" but without success. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can right click any node and select "Publish" - then check "Publish X and all its subpages" as well as "Include unpublished child pages".

Comment: You have to right click the parent node (the very top gray one) for it to work. My answer might be a bit misleading. For it to work, the parent of the node you right click on *must* be published. BTW, it's been a year since you asked, I hope you haven't been stuck since then :-D

Comment: haha you're right, I didn't refresh the umbraco config. Well I didn't stuck but the project didn't progress too much. Thanks! :)